# Using _.some in lodash

Tags: arrays, typescript, lodash

I have Typescript code where i want to return true if any items in 1 array are present in another array. I am new to lodash but i was looking to do this using _.some. I am not sure if this is the correct approach. The code below is returning false but i expected it to return true.

```js
let array1 = ["test", "some", "lodash"];
let array2 = ["some", "includes"];

let condition : boolean = _.some(array1, array2);
```

Comment: Without lodash you can do this using `let condition : boolean = array1.some(e => array2.includes(e));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`intersection`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#intersection) function and check if it returns any items:

```
let condition : boolean = _.intersection(array1, array2).length > 0;
```

With `some` you have to pass a test callback as a second argument:

```
let condition : boolean = _.some(array1, item => array2.includes(item))
```

Comment: what if we need to check all the items of array 2 present in array 1?

Answer (score 0):

lodash was cool before plain javascript had the same methods...

```js
let array1 = ["test", "some", "lodash"];
let array2 = ["some", "includes"];

let test = array1.some(e => array2.includes(e));

console.log(test);
```

Comment: _.some is for objects while javascript .some is for arrays